# htaccess change URL without showing in browser address bar

Tags: apache, .htaccess

On my apache server I would like to redirect requests for

> mydomain.com/?XYZ

to

> mydomain.com/new

This is straight forward, BUT, I don't want the new address to show in the user's browser address bar.  So I can't use a 301/302.  Here's what I have so far

This condition works fine:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^XYZ$ [NC]
```

This redirect works but browser sees new address

```
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/new? [L]
```

This redirect works but browser sees new address

```
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ new? [R=301,L]
```

This redirect does not work (but no error in apache log), just serves up the defaul index.php with the original query string attached

```
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ new? [L]
```

Can someone help with a rule that tells apache to grab the right file without notifying the browser of the change?

---

In case it matters, this is on a Bitnami server on AWS (Wordpress MU).  Bitnami disables .htaccess and moves all rules to httpd-app.conf file.  I didn't think this would affect rule processing...but just in case

Comment: I tried in new browser but same result.  In case it matters, this is on a Bitnami AWS guest, running Wordpress MU.  Bitnami disables .htaccess and moves rules into httpd-app.conf file.  Rules are identical just in different file.  No idea if that can be a cause?

Comment: Wordpress doesn't work with internal rewrite rules. You will have to use WP rewrite API to write these rules in `functions.php` file.

Comment: I want to do this at the apache level (before Wordpress sees anything).  The first three rules work (just sending a 302) so this approach should work.  Just for some reason the rewrite of the querystring isn't working as expected.  Or, are you saying that Wordpress affects apache's interpretation of the querystring?

Comment: 301/301 will work fine but **internal rewrite rules** (ones that don't change URL in browser) won't work with WP. So even `RewriteRule ^foo$ bar [L]` won't work.

Comment: That's interesting - can you explain why?  I thought Apache would change the URL before a php/html file is even fetched (so before Wordpress' PHP files even see it).   How does Wordpress' PHP files even know about the change that happens at the apache level?

Comment: WP front controller works with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` value but it remains unchanged for an internal rewrite rule.

Comment: But that's inside Wordpress' PHP code ($_SERVER variables).  By the time Apache executes the PHP script hasn't the URI already been rewritten?  Still don't understand how this could be

Comment: `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is what was originally requested, before any internal rewrites happened.

Comment: That makes sense.  This may be useful to others working in Wordpress.  If you want to post as answer I would accept that